# ValueError: "concat" mode can only merge layers with matching output shapes except for the concat axis

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, image-segmentation, kaggle

I am trying to classify, Identify(location) and segmentation of the LAS data(Drone data)like buildings, trees and roads using https://github.com/ternaus/kaggle_dstl_submission.  When i ran the building prediction code ([python make_prediction_cropped_buildings.p](https://github.com/ternaus/kaggle_dstl_submission/blob/master/src/make_prediction_cropped_buildings.py)y)I am facing below issue:

```
Using TensorFlow backend.

architecture_128_50_buildings_3_.json

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "make_prediction_cropped_buildings.py", line 26, in <module>
    model = read_model()
  File "make_prediction_cropped_buildings.py", line 21, in read_model
    model = model_from_json(open(os.path.join('../src/cache', json_name)).read())
  File "/home/darshan/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/models.py", line 214, in model_from_json
    return layer_from_config(config, custom_objects=custom_objects)
  File "/home/darshan/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/utils/layer_utils.py", line 44, in layer_from_config
    custom_objects=custom_objects)
  File "/home/darshan/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/engine/topology.py", line 2597, in from_config
    process_layer(layer_data)
  File "/home/darshan/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/engine/topology.py", line 2593, in process_layer
    layer(input_tensors)
  File "/home/darshan/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/engine/topology.py", line 1470, in __call__
    node_indices, tensor_indices)
  File "/home/darshan/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/engine/topology.py", line 1380, in _arguments_validation
    'Layer shapes: %s' % (input_shapes))

ValueError: "concat" mode can only merge layers with matching output shapes except for the concat axis. Layer shapes: [(None, 1024, 14, 7), (None, 256, 14, 14)]
```

Comment: Without your code or the part of it that is broken no one will be able to help you.

Comment: Thanks, Daniel, I added github link in the description and again I am adding here also https://github.com/ternaus/kaggle_dstl_submission/blob/master/src/make_prediction_cropped_buildings.py

Comment: keras version 1.2.2, also tried with 1.2.1 and 1.2.0. and keras.json {
    "image_dim_ordering": "tf",
    "epsilon": 1e-07,
    "floatx": "float32",
     "backend": "tensorflow"
}

Comment: also added "image_data_format": "channels_first" to keras json file,still not working